# Why do I need `to_s` on top of `to_i` when reading from a file?

Tags: ruby, string

I read a number `"98"` from a file, and tried to convert it to binary using `input.to_i(2)`, but I get `0` that way.

```
input=File.read("input.dat")
puts "Input is: #{input}"
puts "Normal way is #{input.to_i(2)}"
puts "It works this way #{input.to_i.to_s(2)}"
puts "Calling the number directly works #{98.to_s(2)}"
```

Output is:

```
Input is: 98
Normal way is 0
It works this way 1100010
Calling the number directly works 1100010
```

Comment: Generally, if you're reading values from a file I'd recommend you save them as YAML or maybe JSON. The values will be automatically be converted back to their native type, which helps avoid this sort of confusion. @sawa's answer directly deals with the problem you're seeing, but you might want to reconsider how to store the data on disk. (As is, I think this is an XY problem where storage is the real problem. Reading the data will fall into place with the right storage method.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`to_i(2)` interprets an expression in a string as a binary number, which should only consist of `"0"` and `"1"`. Since `"98"` is invalid, the result becomes `0` by default, by design. (It could have been alternatively designed to return `nil` or raise an error, but somehow it is designed this way.)

To display a number as binary, you need `to_s(2)` because that gives the expression of the number in binary.

As a number, there is no distinction between binary number, decimal number etc. All there is is a number. What those notions with binary, decimal, etc. are about is the way they are expressed as a string.

Comment: Hey sawa thanks a lot! This was really what I needed to know. I don't know why a binary number cannot be an integer since technically they are but now I understand why Ruby rejects them.